# Multiple SSIS Packages failing during ftp during ftp.GetDetailListing?

Tags: vb.net, ssis, ftp

I have a whole bunch of SSIS packages that are failing during the GetDetailListing within an ftp script component of SSIS jobs.  These were all working fine for years up until about 1.5 days ago.  Currently they are all failing.  We have traced it to the point of being the fact that the ftp itself is not set to passive.  We can set the FtpClientConnection setting like this. :

```
FtpClientConnection.UsePassiveMode = True
```

Upon setting the above prior to the ftp connection being set, it will connect and work without error.  What I am trying to determine prior to going through and fixing all these packages.  Is what would have changed that would cause all ftps that were previously not set to passive to now require passive?  At first I thought it was some sort of network setting or something of that sort but have been unable to determine what that would be.  I can't believe that all  the ftp locations that we were connecting to would have performed a security update all at the same time.

Any ideas?  I am stumped and have been looking at this for > 8 hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being our barracuda server.  Upon being rebooted these failures just disappeared.  An auto update to this server must have been the cause to all these issues.